# Overlaying color on a NON rectangle shade

Tags: core-graphics, heatmap, drawrect, uicolor

I am creating a heat map as an overlay for an image, the sections of the heat map are not rectangles and thus makes it a bit more difficult to overlay a color because when you overlay a color of the image it also hits the transparent pixels of the image. What is the best way to go about this?

The first image is what I am trying to overlay, and the second is the end result I am looking for...

[image: I am overlaying colors on this image in sections of the court]
[image: This is the end result I am looking for]

Answer (score 1):

Use [Bézier paths](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/), [Bézier paths](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBezierPath_Class/), [Bézier paths](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000950-CH1g-TPXREF106), or [Bézier paths](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/).

See also [the section of the Quartz 2D Programming Guide about Bézier paths](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html).